AxiosError: Network Error when calling API from react native in django rest framework
I am running my app on my android device and i am not using any emulator. From postman I can call the APIs defined in django rest framework, however, when calling them from the front end, I am receiving the following error:
AxiosError: Network Error
Settings.py:
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cadence',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ( 
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ) 
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

SpitifyViews.py:
class SpotifyViews(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create_spotify_token(request):
        try:
            url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
            headers = {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
            data = {
                "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                "client_id": "{my client id}",
                "client_secret": "{my client secret}"
            }

            encoded_data = urlencode(data)
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=encoded_data)

            if response.status_code == 200:
               return JsonResponse(response.json())
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Failed to get Spotify token"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            
        except Exception as error:
            return JsonResponse({"error": str(error)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

JS Code:
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";

export const sendRequest = async (method, endpoint, body) => {
    const response = await axios.request({
        method: method,
        url: endpoint,
        data: body,
        headers: {
            // Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
    });

    if (response.status === 401) {
        // do somethinhg
    }

    return response;
};

const handleSignUp = async () =>{
  console.log("signed up")
  router.push("/login")
  if(!info.email || !info.username || !info.password){
    Alert.alert("Error", "All fields are required")
    return
  }
  setIsSubmitting(true)
  console.log(info)
  try{
    const response = await sendRequest(requestMehods.POST, "cadence/api/user/register/", {
      ...info,
    });
    console.log("response")
    if (response.data.status === "success") {
      // do somethinhg
      router.push("/registration")
    }
  } catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  } finally {
    setIsSubmitting(false)
  }
};

Any idea what could be the reason?

Does this answer your question? React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API

Could you provide more extensive logging from the client side and, if possible,or if it exists, from the server side? Network Error could be a number of issues!

To connect react native to django server, run the server on your ip instead of localhost. This assumes your ip is 10.0.0.49
python manage.py runserver 10.0.0.49:8000

Then change the frontend baseURL to
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://10.0.0.49:8000/";

I had this problem with my django rn project too a while back, very frustrating
